# Single complex command to find, tar, and zip files on AIX

Tags: linux, find, zip, tar, aix

I have a long Linux csh command that finds/tars/and zips all files in all subdirectories of a directory. It looks like this:

```
find /dir1/dir2/* -mtime -1 -type -f -print0 | xargs -0 tar -zcf /dir1/dir3/log_archive.tar.gz
```

I modified it for AIX to look like this (We have both Linux and AIX boxes on our system.):

```
find /dir1/dir2/* -mtime -1 -type -f -print | xargs tar -cf /dir1/dir3/log_archive.tar
```

This only creates the tar file since AIX doesn't allow the z(ip) option on the tar command. I'm struggling with adding the zip part to it.

I know I can create a multi line script and will do it if I have to. I'd rather keep it a single executable command so I can add it to crontab as a single line. It works great on Linux.

Comment: This part is plain wrong: `/dir1/dir2/*` -- use a single directory name without any wildcards.

Comment: Well, AIX seems to be plain wrong. Help me understand why the wildcard is wrong. The find works with or without the wildcard. Unfortunately, everything under dir2 is being tar'd up instead of only files within the last day. The "-type f" also seems to have no bearing.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong, you can specify multiple starting points (with or without wildcard).

Comment: How do you specify multiple starting points?

Comment: `find /opt /dev /usr/local/* -name 'findme.txt'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the output of `tar` to `gzip`.

```
find /dir1/dir2/* -mtime -1 -type -f -print | xargs tar -cf - | gzip > /dir1/dir3/log_archive.tar.gz
```

`-` in place of the output filename means to write the archive to standard output, so you can pipe to another command.

Comment: Thank you I was missing the "-" after tar -cf. Can you tell me what that - does?

Comment: As with most commands, using `-` in place of a filename means to use stdin or stdout, depending on whether it's replacing an input or output file.

Comment: I have a new problem. The max number of files I am able to get into the tar.gz file is 4093. I can't get 4094. I think it is due to the command line limit to xargs. I do the same thing on Linux servers and am able to overcome the limit using the "xargs -s" option to increase the size of the command line. That same option, although described in the AIX man page for xargs, does not seem to take the same large number Linux takes. On Linux I can look up the max command line length using "xargs --show-limit" but that doesn't work on AIX. Any ideas how I can increase the command line length?

Comment: You may need to install the GNU version of `xargs` on AIX to get that feature.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Turns out the solution was easy. Instead of making a single complex command I made separate commands on one line and separated them with semicolons.

Comment: I don't understand how that works if you don't create a pipeline. Each command will just send its output to the terminal instead of the next program.

Comment: The find creates a temp file with the filenames in it. This list is used to create a temp tar. The 3rd command zips the tar file.  Finally the temp files are deleted